# IDictonary<string,IParameter>

Tags: c#-3.0

I am `IDictionary<string, IParameter> QueryParameters` and trying to assign values to it, however i am failed.

Sample code:

```
public IDictionary<string, IParameter> QueryParameters 
{ 
  get 
  { 
     return new Dictionary<string, IParameter>(); 
  } 
}
```

Please can someone provide some example or let me know how to assign values to IParameter.

Comment: Do you mean System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you return a new instance everytime. Try:

```
private readonly IDictionary<string, IParameter> m_QueryParameters = new Dictionary<string, IParameter>(); 

public IDictionary<string, IParameter> QueryParameters 
{ 
  get { return m_QueryParameters; } 
}
```

Now you can use it:

```
QueryParameters.Add( "key", new Parameter() );
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, however new Parameter() is an WebControls.Parameter and it can't be converted to Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces.IParameter

Comment: Yes, I didn't know your name for the concrete class of `IParameter`. The name `Parameter` was just a guess. You have to use your class that is implementing `IParameter`, here.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a new `IDictionary<string, IParameter>` instance each time the `QueryParameters` property is called.

You should probably keep this instance in the containing class:

```
class Foo
{
  private IDictionary<string, IParameter> dict =
    new Dictionary<string, IParameter>();

  public IDictionary<string, IParameter> QueryParameters 
  { 
    get
    {
      return dict;
    } 
  }
}
```

and then use it as follows:

```
void SomeFunc
{
   Foo f = new Foo();
   f.QueryParameters.Add("name", new Parameter());
   f.QueryParameters.Add("something else", new Parameter());
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, however new Parameter() is an WebControls.Parameter and it can't be converted to Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces.IParameter

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain what you are asking as you don't assign to IParameter which is a type. What you do is create a variable that has a type of IParameter and assign to that. Yo be more complete I assume that IParameter is an interface and so you need a concrete class that extends IParameter and create an instance of that.

Thus somewhwre

class Parameter extends IParameter
   {
   ... 
   }

Your code

IDictionary dict = obj. QueryParameters();   // get the dictionary from your method
   Parameter para = new Parameter();

dict.Add("test", para);

Also see dalle's answer for improvments to you class shown